# Simple relationships not mapped with queryForObject

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have one question. I am using neo4j-ogm snapshot 1.5 .
I have the following classes:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class Entity {
    @GraphId
    protected Long id;

    @Expose
    protected String code = null;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) 
            return true;

        if (o == null || id == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) 
            return false;

        Entity entity = (Entity) o;

        if (!id.equals(entity.id)) 
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (id == null) ? -1 : id.hashCode();
    }

    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long neo4jId){
        this.id = neo4jId;
    }

    public String getCode(){
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }
}



public class PropertyGroup extends Entity{

    @Expose
    private String name;

    public PropertyGroup(){

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


public class User  extends Entity {
    private Long registration_date;

    private Long last_login_date;

    private Boolean is_admin = false;

    private String push_dev;

    private String push_id;

    private Boolean push_enabled = false;

    @Expose
    private String avatar;
    @Expose
    private String avatarUrl;
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @Expose
    private volatile String password;
    @Expose
    private int likes = 0;
    @Expose
    private int questionCount = 0;
    @Expose
    private int followersCount = 0;
    @Expose
    private boolean isFollowing = false;


//  public Set<UserPropertyRelation> properties;

//  @Relationship(type = ModelRelType.ANSWERED)
//  public Set<UserAnsweredRelation> userAnswers;
//
//  @Relationship(type = ModelRelType.LIKES)
//  private Set<LikesQuestionRelation> questionsLiked;



    @Expose
    @Relationship(type = ModelRelType.HAS_PROPERTY)
    private Set<PropertyGroup> properties;

//  private Profile userProfile;

//  private List<Fact> facts;
//  @Expose
//  @Relationship(type = ModelRelType.OWNS)
//  private List<Question> questions;

    public User(){
//      this.properties = new LinkedHashSet<UserPropertyRelation>();
//      this.userAnswers = new LinkedHashSet<UserAnsweredRelation>();
//      this.userProperties = new HashSet<PropertyGroup>();
//      this.setFacts(new ArrayList<Fact>());
        this.properties = new HashSet<PropertyGroup>();
    }

    public User(long regDate, long lastLoginDate, boolean isAdmin, 
            String pushDev, String pushId, boolean pushEnabled){
        this();
        this.registration_date = regDate;
        this.last_login_date = lastLoginDate;
        this.is_admin = isAdmin;
        this.push_dev = pushDev;
        this.push_id = pushId;
        this.push_enabled = pushEnabled;    
    }

//  public void addUserAnsweredRelation(UserAnsweredRelation answer){
//      answer.setStartNode(this);
//      this.userAnswers.add(answer);
//  }
//  
//  public Set<UserAnsweredRelation> getUserAnsweredRelations() {
//      return this.userAnswers;
//  }

//  public void setUserAnsweredRelations(Set<UserAnsweredRelation> userAnswers){
//      for(UserAnsweredRelation a : userAnswers){
//          a.setStartNode(this);
//      }
//      
//      this.userAnswers = userAnswers;
//  }
//  
//  public void addUserPropertyRelation(UserPropertyRelation rel){
//      rel.setUser(this);
//      properties.add(rel);
//  }
//  
//  public void setUserPropertyRelations(Set<UserPropertyRelation> properties){
//      for(UserPropertyRelation r: properties){
//          r.setUser(this);
//      }
//      
//      this.properties = properties;
//  }

//  public Set<UserPropertyRelation> getUserPropertyRelations(){
//      return this.properties;
//  }

    public long getRegistrationDate() {
        return registration_date;
    }

    public void setRegistrationDate(long registrationDate) {
        this.registration_date = registrationDate;
    }

    public long getLastLoginDate() {
        return last_login_date;
    }

    public void setLastLoginDate(long lastLoginDate) {
        this.last_login_date = lastLoginDate;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return is_admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean isAdmin) {
        this.is_admin = isAdmin;
    }

    public String getPushDev() {
        return push_dev;
    }

    public void setPushDev(String pushDev) {
        this.push_dev = pushDev;
    }

    public String getPushId() {
        return push_id;
    }

    public void setPushId(String pushId) {
        this.push_id = pushId;
    }

    public boolean isPushEnabled() {
        return push_enabled;
    }

    public void setPushEnabled(boolean pushEnabled) {
        this.push_enabled = pushEnabled;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<PropertyGroup> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Set<PropertyGroup> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

//  public Profile getUserProfile() {
//      return userProfile;
//  }
//
//  public void setUserProfile(Profile userProfile) {
//      this.userProfile = userProfile;
//  }

//  public Set<LikesQuestionRelation> getQuestionsLiked() {
//      return questionsLiked;
//  }
//
//  public void setQuestionsLiked(Set<LikesQuestionRelation> likes) {
//      this.questionsLiked = likes;
//  }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

//  public List<Fact> getFacts() {
//      return facts;
//  }
//
//  public void setFacts(List<Fact> facts) {
//      this.facts = facts;
//  }

    public String getAvatarUrl() {
        return avatarUrl;
    }

    public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
        this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    }

    public int getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(int likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    public int getQuestionCount() {
        return questionCount;
    }

    public void setQuestionCount(int questionCount) {
        this.questionCount = questionCount;
    }

    public int getFollowersCount() {
        return followersCount;
    }

    public void setFollowersCount(int followersCount) {
        this.followersCount = followersCount;
    }

    public boolean isFollowing() {
        return isFollowing;
    }

    public void setFollowing(boolean isFollowing) {
        this.isFollowing = isFollowing;
    }

//  public List<Question> getQuestions() {
//      return questions;
//  }
//
//  public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
//      this.questions = questions;
//  }
```

When I am trying to do the following:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(modelsPackageName);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(url);

        String cypher = "MATCH (u:User {code: {CODE}})-[h:HAS_PROPERTY]->(pg:PropertyGroup) " +
                "RETURN u, h, pg";

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("CODE", "fc48b19ba6f8427a03d6e5990bcef99a28f55592b80fe38731cf805ed188cabf");
//      System.out.println(Util.mergeParamsWithCypher(cypher, params));
        User u = session.queryForObject(User.class, cypher, params);
```

The user Object (u) never contains any properties (PropertyGroup entity is not mapped).

What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `queryForObject` return just one column- the object, in your case `u`.
Neo4j OGM 1.x does not support mapping of custom query results to domain entities, so you will have to return the entity ID, and then do an additional load-by-id specifying a custom depth.

OGM 2.0 (currently 2.0.0-M01) does support mapping custom query results to entities. Your query will remain the same (i.e. `return u,h,pg`) but instead you'll use the `query()` method that returns a `Result`. From the result, you'll be able to get your User entity by column-name `u` and it'll be hydrated with the PropertyGroups it is related to.

**Update:**
The dependencies for OGM 2.0.0-M01 are

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.0-M01</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.0-M01</version>
    </dependency>
```

Be sure to read the about the configuration changes since you're upgrading from OGM 1.x http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/2.0.0-M01/#reference_setup

A summary of new features: http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-ogm-2-0-milestone-1/

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Where do I actually get OGM 2.0 from? I always used the git repositor: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/ which gives me neo4j-ogm-1.1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar. Regards

Comment: Hey Luanne, I am actually pretty new to maven. What I tried so far is to clone the current git repository with: git clone https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm.git  . After downloading the data I modified the root pom.xml file according to your suggestions (including the two dependencies). However, this seems to build the 1.1.5 snapshot. What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated. Regards, Alex

Comment: I managed to compile and configure the OGM 2.x version. However I really don't get the point, how one would get the User object from a Result object. What I do for now is getting the Iterator from the Result. and getting the first entry with Iterator.next(), which gives me a Map<String, Object> . When I get the "u" entry it actually returns a LinkedHashMap which can't be cast to User. So how do I get the User object hydrated with the PropertyGroups? I tried to convert the LinkedHashMap with Gson and Jackson respectively, leading to a User object not being linked to any PropertyGroups :-( .

Comment: Are you sure you're on 2.0.0-M01 or 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT? The behaviour you describe is 1.x

Comment: What is further confusing me is the fact, that when I use queryForObject with the new OGM 2.x it gives me the desired result. Whereas I don't see any possibility to get the User Object and all its connected parts from the Result object. There is at least no way to do it automatically. This widely diverges from what is written in the documentation. Another thing I would like to mention is that the driver seems to fail in kinds of Base64 encoding. username and password seem not to be encoded when supplied in form of a configuration file. I have to manually setCredentials programatically. Regards

Comment: Yeah I am actually using the builds from yesterday:

Comment: Yeah I am using the snapshots from yesterday: neo4j-ogm-api-2.0.0-20160202.055512-1.jar, neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-20160202.055550-1.jar and neo4j-ogm-drivers-2.0.0-20160202.055528-1.jar

Comment: Do you have some links to compiled jars I could use? Sounds like I am using the wrong jars but I actually took those from: https://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/neo4j/

Comment: queryForObject always mapped the result to a domain entity, it isn't a new feature of OGM 2.x 
OGM 2.x will map your User object in the Result but your dependencies don't seem right. You also need the neo4j-ogm-compilers. Not sure what else you're missing, a build system such as maven would pull those in for you. Not sure what you mean about encoding credentials- what you supply in the config file is exactly what is supplied to the driver.

Comment: Hey Luanna, everything is working the way it should. Thanks for your hints etc. Regarding the encoding thing. What I meant is that the password if supplied via config file is not base64 encoded. It is passed in as is. It would be a nice feature to add that if you ask me, as actually the setCredentials method seems to base64 encode the password if set programmatically. Thanks for your help and have a nice day. Regards, Alex